# SQL Server 2008 - Slow With Filter A Specific Value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am facing a weird issue and hoping that someone can advise me where/how to troubleshoot this.

Basically, I have a big query, join multiple tables, then wrap it with a outside query to do the filtering.  This query returns really fast with selecting everything (no filter) or filter with Region = 1.

So if I run these queries, they run fast as normal.

```
Select * from (
    select query...... join multiple tables.
    Return all records.
) a

OR

Select * from (
    select query...... join multiple tables.
    Return will records with RegionID = 1
) a
Where Region = 1
```

However, when I change to Region = 2, it is very slow. Note that `Region` value is either 1 or 2. I am not sure why it causes slow when I just change the value from 1 = 2. Any thoughts?

```
Select * from (
    select query...... join multiple tables.
    Return will records with RegionID = 2
) a
Where Region = 2
```

Thank you,

Comment: Have you checked the execution plans for both queries?

Comment: Look at the execution plans to see if they differ when you change the condition. Whether indices are used etc.

Comment: I click "Display Estimated Execution Plan", so I look at the Cost %, correct?  I don't know how to use Execution Plan. please advise.

Comment: The slow query has multple higher % of Cost. any advise how to troubleshoot that?  Not sure why if I query everything is faster than with the filter?

Comment: For starters, you want to use *Actual* Execution Plan.  This requires that you rerun the query after you turn this feature on.

Comment: Thanks @Phil, I tried as you suggested. In the Execution Plan, it said "Missing Index (Inpact 13.9419) : Create NonClustered Index [<Name of Missing Index, sysname, >] ON [dbo].[Table] ([RecordID]).  Any advise where I should start trace the problem?

Comment: You could add that index and see if that fixes the problem.  However, this is not a good long-term strategy for creating indexes--you want to look at the big picture and create sensible indexes based on how the tables in your database are queried.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you executed the "Region = 1" several times and the result has been cached.
Have you tried cleaning cache?

```
CHECKPOINT; 
GO 
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS; 
GO
```